# How to factorise $16x^4+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’ve no idea how to factorise $16x^4+1$ because it has no real roots. It only comes out with $\sqrt{i}/2$ and $-\sqrt{i}/2$ What method should I use.

Comment: Try the Sophie-Germain identity https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Sophie_Germain_Identity

Answer (score 2):

It has no real roots so if it factors, it must factor into quadratics.  Try

$$16x^4+1 = (ax^2+bx+1)(cx^2+dx+1)$$ $$ = acx^4+(ad+bc)x^2+(a+c+bd)c^2 + (b+d)x + 1.$$

Comparing coefficients, you have $b+d=0$, so $b=-d$.  Put that in the second coefficient to get $-ab+bc = 0$ so that $a=c$.  Then the first coefficient gives $a^2=16$, so $a=c=4$.  The middle coefficient forces $b=\pm\sqrt{8}$.  So youhave

$$(4x^2+\sqrt{8}x+1)(4x^2-\sqrt{8}x+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

The Sophie-Germain identity could help significantly

**Hint:** $a^4 + 4b^4 = (a^2 + 2b^2 + 2ab)(a^2 + 2b^2 - 2ab)$

Answer (score 0):

$$4n^4+1=(2n^2+1)^2-2\cdot2n^2\cdot1=?$$

Here $n=2x$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,\alpha=(1+i)/2\sqrt 2\,\,$ be a square root of $i/4$. Then the roots of $16x^4+1$ are $\alpha,\bar{\alpha},-\alpha,$ and $-\bar{\alpha}$.

So $\,(x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha})=x^2-(\alpha+\bar{\alpha})x+\alpha\bar{\alpha}\,\,$ is a factor of $16x^4+1$, with real coefficients. You can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha$ is a root of $16x^4+1$ then
$$-1=16\alpha^4=(2\alpha)^4,$$
which suggests that $(2\alpha)^2=\pm i$. This you can solve with the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+16x%5E4%2B1) sees these as the factors of $16x^4+1$ so I guess you are right about no real roots.

$$((-1)^{1/4} - 2 x)\times ((-1)^{3/4} - 2 x)\times (2 x + (-1)^{1/4})\times (2 x + (-1)^{3/4})$$

Another look at "solving" the equation is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+16x%5E4%2B1).